# authblk messes up \AA command in \author and \affil with pdflatex

Tags: authblk

The following example compiled with pdflatex (MikTeX on Windows 10)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{{\AA}lesund is a nice city}
\author[1]{{\AA}ge}
\affil[1]{NTNU, {\AA}lesund}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
The name should be `{\AA}ge', the affiliation `{\AA}lesund'.
\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

i.e., the accent on Å's in \author and \affil fields is on a wrong place.

Using `\r{A}` does not help.
Adding `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` and replacing `\AA` with `Å` does not work either, neither does `[utf8]` encoding.
On the other hand, xelatex produces the correct output both with `\AA` and with `Å`.

Is this a known issue/bug, or should I report it somewhere?

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, that tells LaTeX `\AA` is a real letter from the font, not an A that LaTeX should add a ring to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

This tells (pdf)LaTeX that it can find many (designed) letters directly in the font, without (and not using xelatex or lualatex), LaTeX will try to add a ring to an A.

BTW: always a good idea to have both `fontenc` and `inputenc` when using (pdf)LaTeX.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Any idea why I need `fontenc` only inside `\author` and `\affil`, while other places it works without?

Comment: It is not just under `\author` and `\affil`. My guess is that this is due to the processing `authblk` performs, it saves stuff in a form of list and something goes nuts somewhere

Answer (score 5):

the package locally redefines `\rlap` to affect the position of footnote marks, but that affects the positioning of the accent  `\r A` in OT1.  You can define the accent not to use `\rlap` but use lower level commands directly

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\r}{OT1}{A}
   {\leavevmode\setbox\z@\hbox{!}\dimen@\ht\z@\advance\dimen@-1ex%
    %\rlap
    \hb@xt@\z@
    {\raise.67\dimen@\hbox{\char23}%
    \hss
    }A}
\makeatother
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{{\AA}lesund is a nice city}
\author[1]{{\AA}ge}
\affil[1]{NTNU, {\AA}lesund}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
The name should be `{\AA}ge', the affiliation `{\AA}lesund'.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have accepted daleif's answer because it provides an easier solution, but this is an interesting explanation of what actually happens.